# how to change the title name of ggplot in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is a loop generate the multiple plots.
My question is I want the title name change for each iteration. for example "plot1","plot2","plot3".........

what if I want a sentence for the plot title, say"This is the 1 plot we have","This is the 2 plot we have"

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a list with a specific length 
plot_lst <- vector("list", length = 8)

for (i in 1:8) {
  g <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt)) +
    geom_point()+ggtitle("plot1")
  plot_lst[[i]] <- g
}

# Combine all plots
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_lst, nrow = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a list with a specific length 
plot_lst <- vector("list", length = 8)

for (i in 1:8) {
  g <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt)) +
    geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("plot",i))
  plot_lst[[i]] <- g
}

# Combine all plots
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_lst, nrow = 4)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what if I want a sentence for the plot title, say"This is the 1 plot we have","This is the 2 plot we have"...............

Comment: You can use in the end of loop this: `+ggtitle(paste0("This is the ",i,"plot we have"))` let me know if that works. Just change last part with the mentionated code!

Comment: works, thanks professor

Comment: @AIKidds Always a pleasure helping you!